# Quite new rails developer confused over content_tag and helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, helper, content-tag

I am trying to create a calendar table to display the daily availability of every staff member of a company. What I think I need is a header with the days of the month and then a row (with as many cells as the number of the days) for each staff member. The different background color of each cell will represent a different availability status and the staff members change so I want all this to be dynamically generated.

After researching online and with [Ryan Bates' Railscast #213 (Calendars Revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars) as my guide, I have so far managed to generate the header of my table that displays the days of the month in each cell.

And that's my code so far:

```
module ReceptionHelper
def reception(date = Date.today, &block)
    Reception.new(self, date, block).table
end

class Reception < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def table
        content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
            daysHeader
        end
    end

    def daysHeader
        last_day = date.end_of_month.strftime("%d").to_i
        (0..last_day).to_a.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
    end
end
```

Now, here is where the questions and confusion begins:

- Removing `&block` and `:callback` takes away the { ... } functionality, as I found out. I can't really say I understand why though. Anyone with a good explanation?
- Why does the above work but I can't use `(..).each do` and the `content_tag` block below?

  ```
  (0..last_day).to_a.each do |day| 
      content_tag :th do
          day
      end
  end
  ```
- In my effort to display the rows for each staff, I went with this:

  ```
  def table
      content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
          daysHeader + staffRows
      end
  end

  def staffRows
      staff.to_a.map { |staff| content_tag :tr, staff.name }.join.html_safe
  end
  ```

  *I added `staff` to the `Reception` class definition and I call with `<%= reception @staff %>` - if that's not a very good practice please feel free to shout at me :D*

  However, instead of getting one row per staff member I get all the member names next to each other in one row and right above the header. Changing `content_tag :tr` to `content_tag :td` results in a cell with the name of each staff after the last header cell.

As you understand, I am quite lost in this and it seems I am not even clearly getting why the part that works as I want it to is correct. I hope this post doesn't give the impression that I am looking to have everything served to me in a dish - I am rather looking for directions that will help me understand. :)

**EDIT:**

I've made some progress by changing the `staffRows` method to this:

```
def staffRows
    staff.to_a.in_groups_of(1).map do |staff|
        content_tag :tr do
            staff.map { |room| content_tag :th, staff.name }.join.html_safe
        end
    end.join.html_safe
end
```

However this produces only one cell for each room while I want a row with as many cells as the header.

Answer (score 6):

First of all ruby conventions: use 2 spaces for spacing and use _ for method names.

Now meet your best friend when writing complex helpers: `concat`. What it does is outputs string directly to ERB buffer. To show you and example:

```
def my_helper
  concat "hello world"
end
<% my_helper %>
```

would output `hello world` in html even though we used `<%` and not `<%=`.

It's very important method when dealing with blocks in helpers, as it means you can call `concat` multiple times in block and both strings will be output. Here's an example:

```
def my_helper
  content_tag :div do
    concat "Hello "
    concat "World"
    concat "!"
  end
end
<%= my_helper %>
```

would output `<div>Hello World!</div>`. So using same idea you could do something like this:

```
def my_helper
  content_tag :ul do
    @people.each do |person|
      concat content_tag(:li, person.name)
    end
  end
end
<%= my_helper %>
```

which would result in something like this: `<ul><li>John Doe</li><li>Mike Tyson</li></ul>`.

So I would rewrite `days_helper` to something like this:

```
def days_header
  (0..date.end_of_month.day).each { |day| concat content_tag(:th, day) }
end
```

do something similar with `staff_rows` method and then `table` method would look simply like this:

```
content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
  days_header
  staff_rows
end
```

As for the callback part of question: `&block` captures block that is passed to method into Proc object. This object can later be passed around to other methods or called directly. As you're not using callback object I would simply advise to remove it.

Comment: Hello @Andrius, thanks a lot for your answer and my apologies for not replying earlier - I never got a notification. I took notes of what you wrote but I'd love your comments on the solution I ended up with, going to post the code here soon.